# git not recognised as an internal and external command

Tags: git

CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You should probably install git, then.

Comment: Install git, and then you can also use Git Bash terminal or if you want you can also use Git GUI.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open up the DOS terminal
2. Type the following command 'echo %path%'. This is your path variable. When you use any command it will look for the installed program in the directories listed. You will notice that  the path to git will not be here
3. Download the latest version of git for Windows from here:  [Latest Git](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full+installer+official+git) and run the installer
4. Make sure you select 'Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt' and finish running the installer
5. Type the following command 'echo %path%'. You should see the path to the git binary is added to your path.
6. Type the command git --version
7. You should see something like git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0